# Minimize $x^2-y^2-z^2$ subject to $x^4+y^4+z^4\leq1$ using KKT Conditions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am having trouble finding finding the KKT points of the following problem.
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\min&{x^2-y^2-z^2}
\\
\text{subject to} & x^4+y^4+z^4\leq1
\end{array}
$$

The Lagrangian is
$$
\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda)=x^2-y^2-z^2+\lambda(x^4+y^4+z^4-1) \quad \lambda\geq0
$$
KKT Conditions:
$$
\begin{align}
& \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x}=2x(1+2\lambda x^2)=0 \\
&\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial y}=2y(-1+2\lambda y^2)=0 \\
& \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial z}=2z(-1+2\lambda z^2)=0 \\
& x^4+y^4+z^4\leq1 \\
& \lambda(x^4+y^4+z^4-1)=0 \\
& \lambda \geq 0 \\
\end{align} 
$$

- If $\lambda =0$ this is easy $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ is a KKT point.
- If $\lambda \neq 0$ didn't manage to solve the system. I tried substituting $x'=x^2,y'=y^2,z'=z^2$. This lead me to the following solutions:
  $$(x',y',z')=(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})$$ and $$(x',y',z')=(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})$$ but because $x',y',z'$ are non-negative they don't seem to help much.

Please advise.

Comment: These are spurious solutions of your substitution. You seem to miss points with $x=0$.

Comment: If $\lambda>0$ then  $x\ne0$ leads to a contradiction in the $dL/dx$ equation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align}
& \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x}=2x(1+2\lambda x^2)=0 \\
&\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial y}=2y(-1+2\lambda y^2)=0 \\
& \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial z}=2z(-1+2\lambda z^2)=0 \\
\end{align}$

From first equation, $\lambda = - \dfrac{1}{2x^2}, \text{ if } x \ne 0$

Plugging into second we get $y^2 = - x^2$ so there is no solution in real.

So taking $x = 0$ from the first equation, from second equation, $\lambda = \dfrac{1}{2y^2}, \text{ if } y \ne 0$

Plugging into third equation, we get $z = \pm y$

Plugging into constraint, we get $(0, \pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[4]2}, \pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[4]2})$ at $\lambda = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you. We also have the case where $y=0$ so then $z=1$ and we get $(0,0,1)$ and $(0,0,-1)$. Am I right?

Comment: @Dennis yes in addition to the points we get directly from Lagrange Multiplier method, we need to test points on the boundary for extrema.

Comment: $(0, 0, 0), (\pm1, 0, 0), (0, \pm 1, 0), (0, 0, \pm 1)$ are all points on the boundary of the given constraint that should be checked.

Comment: Aren't KKT conditions are **necessary** for extrema? (because the the constraint is convex and Slater's condition is satisfied). Meaning that I need only check the KKT points (and take those with the lowest value)?

Comment: Sorry I was away. Yes you are right that you only need to check KKT conditions. I was making a general point. But you must note that points $(0, \pm1, 0)$ and $(0, 0, \pm1)$ are KKT points.

Comment: Thank you very much!